# How to print a pdf file from windows store application

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I am creating a windows 8 app in c# and xaml.
How can i print a pdf file on my system from this app without launching the pdf reader of windows.

Comment: You might be tempted to use an embedded browser with the reader control embedded in it. You can't. The embedded browser you will use is the version of IE that does not support a plug-in. Your best bet is @yms' suggestion or another third party library to accomplish this. You can write your own, of course. But wow.

Answer (score 2):

If a commercial library is an option, you could try [Amyuni PDF Creator for WinRT](http://www.amyuni.com/en/resources/trialdownloads/).

[From the documentation](http://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Amyuni_PDF_Creator_for_WinRT/Printing_Documents/Printing_a_PDF_from_a_Windows_Store_Application.htm), the code for printing a PDF file in C# using this library would look like this:

```
// Printing on a XAML Windows Store Application
// The field AmyuniPDFCreator.PDFCreator m_pdfCreator; contains an instance of the PDFCreator control
TypedEventHandler<PrintManager, PrintTaskRequestedEventArgs> m_printTaskRequestedEventToken;
// Registering the Application View for printing
void RegisterForPrinting()
{
    // Request a PrintManager instance
    PrintManager printMan = PrintManager.GetForCurrentView();
    // Add a handler for printing events.
    m_printTaskRequestedEventToken = printMan.PrintTaskRequested += m_pdfCreator.Document.PrintTaskRequestedEventHandler;
}
// Unregistering the Application View for printing
void UnregisterForPrinting()
{
    // Remove the handler for printing events.
    PrintManager printMan = PrintManager.GetForCurrentView();
    printMan.PrintTaskRequested -= m_printTaskRequestedEventToken;
}
```

More details about the library can be found [here](http://www.w8pdf.com).

*Disclaimer: I currently work as a developer of the library*

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to achieve this without any third party library if you want to print it with a device.

This isn't working to create or write a ".pdf"[Pdf File). To make this happen without another library you could maybe try to write images directly into a pdf, but i can only reference here the Pdf Documentation.

First of all you have to render your pdf. You can do this with [`Windows.Data.Pdf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.data.pdf.aspx).
You can take a look at an example [here](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-8.1-Create-a-PDF-Viewer-with-new-PDF-API.aspx). The libary will handle the Pdf and you get some `BitmapImages` rendered.
This library can read, but not write ".pdf"

Now you have to print your Images(rendered pdf pages). For this you take the [`Windows.Graphics.Printing.PrintManager`](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2012/10/25/windows-store-apps-and-xaml-based-printing-rough-notes.aspx).
I would not recommend the msdn example in this case. 
So have a first look at [Windows Store Apps and XAML Based Printing](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2012/10/25/windows-store-apps-and-xaml-based-printing-rough-notes.aspx).

And you will find another printing example with MVVM here: [Printing from MVVM XAML Windows 8 Store apps](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2013/01/20/Printing-from-MVVM-XAML-Windows-8-Store-apps.aspx).

If you just follow the examples you will achieve to print a pdf on paper some trouble.

How to  add custom settings for your printer is explained at [How to add custom settings to the print preview UI (XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh973533.aspx)!

Comment: Just a small remark, if I remember correctly  Windows.Data.Pdf API was introduced with Windows 8.1, so this approach will not work on Windows 8 systems (albeit there are not many of those left out-there)

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 doesn't have an API to do this, so you'll have to acquire one elsewhere - something that's capable of properly rendering a PDF for you, and that's going to mean a full-blown PDF API with all the bells and whistles (I'm not aware of any of these for Windows 8 that only supports printing).

If only [PDF Sharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/%28S%28lojvb5z42qrlrw4yywbfrw3f%29%29/default.aspx) had a WinRT version, I'd recommend it in a heartbeat... unfortunately it doesn't (yet).  Only ones I know of that have an API for WinRT are [Foxit](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/mswin8metro/) and [Siberix Report Writer](http://www.siberix.com/).

Comment: AFAIK, Siberix Report Writer does not render or print PDF files.